# CMake not providing "Findlibusb-1.0.cmake" error

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am receiving the following CMake Error:

> Errors     << project_ros:cmake
>   /home/nando/project_ws/logs/project_ros/build.cmake.020.log CMake
>   Error at /home/nando/project_ws/src/project_ros/CMakeLists.txt:22
>   (find_package):   By not providing "Findlibusb-1.0.cmake" in
>   CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project   has asked CMake to find a package
>   configuration file provided by   "libusb-1.0", but CMake did not find
>   one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libusb-1.0"
>   with   any of the following names:
>
> ```
> libusb-1.0Config.cmake
> libusb-1.0-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "libusb-1.0" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
>   set   "libusb-1.0_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
>   files.  If   "libusb-1.0" provides a separate development package or
>   SDK, be sure it has   been installed.

However, I think I am providing "Findlibusb-1.0.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH correctly.
This is in my CMakeLists.txt:

> set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}
>   "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/project_ros/cmakeModules/")

And in src/project_ros/cmakeModules I have [Findlibusb-1.0.cmake](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/cmake_modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake).

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598631/cmake-cant-find-findlibusb-cmake-in-cmake-module-path-despite-it-being-there) the same error was appearing but the reason was a typo I don't have.

Any other idea?

Comment: From terminal type `sudo locate libusb-1.0Config.cmake`. 
This will print path where your libusb-1.0Config.cmake is present.Give this path in command line with cmake. For e.g. `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=your_config.cmake` .

Comment: If you *top-level* `CMakeLists.txt` is `/home/nando/project_ws/src/project_ros/CMakeLists.txt` one, then you should append `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmakeModules/` (without `project_ros/` component) to *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable. In any case, add `message("CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")` before call to `find_package(libusb-1.0)` and check whether path to your script `Findlibusb-1.0.cmake` is there.

Comment: @Tsyvarev that was the problem, thank you very much.

Comment: you don't need make an extra module. If libusb-1.0 has pkgconfig entry you can use it with cmake.